# Generate temporary csv from sheet then attach to email without saving

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I generate a temporary csv from a sheet of an xlsm file.

Below saves it locally. I only need it to be emailed.

```vb
Sub ExportSheetAsCSVAndEmail3()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wbExport As Workbook
    Dim csvFile As String
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Testinfo")
    
    Set wbExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
    ws.Copy Before:=wbExport.Worksheets(wbExport.Worksheets.Count)
    
    csvFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv"
    wbExport.SaveAs FileName:=csvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .To = "Test@Test.com"
        .subject = "CSV Exported"
        .body = "As attached."
        .Attachments.Add csvFile
        .Send
    End With
    
    wbExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

It seems you must save a copy of the generated csv locally then reference it as the attached. This would cause a pile of unnecessary csv files on the machine over time.

There is the `Kill` function to remove the csv after its emailed but that requires elevated rights so it's not practical.

Is there is a workaround like referencing it from memory?

Comment: I don't think there is way to do what you want. The file should be existing first before you can attach it. But you can try saving your CSV file in temp folder `%temp%` (which gets cleaned at an interval) so the machine will not pile up unnecessary files.